# 2D lattice, potential

Tags: solid-state-physics, lattice-model

When calculating the fourier coefficients of the potential of the following lattice (the potential is a sum of deltas at the atom sites):

[image]

1. I get the wrong coefficients if I choose the following primitve cell, with primitve vectors a1,a2: [image]

And the right coefficients if I choose the following primitve cell:
[image]

**Question:** What's wrong with the first choice?

***First choice:***

$U_K=\int_{primitve cell} \textbf[\delta(r)+\delta(r-a1)+\delta(r-a1-\frac{1}{2}a2)+\delta(r-a1-a2)+\delta(r-a2) +\delta(r-\frac{1}{2})+\delta(r-\frac{1}{2}a1-\frac{1}{2}a2)\textbf]\space e^{-i K r}\space dr $

for $K=\frac{2\pi}{a}(m,n)$ I then get $U_K= 1+(-1)^m+(-1)^{m+n}$

***Second choice***(the right one):

$U_K=1+(-1)^m + (-1)^n$

Comment: I think your second choice describes a Bravais lattice for the vacancies. But the first does not seem do describe the right Bravais Lattice for the atoms. Not sure that is the right reason but there is something about the periodicity.